# Parallel tree search

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Let's say I have a lazy `Tree` whose leaves are possible solutions to a problem

```
data Tree a = Node [Tree a] | Leaf (Maybe a)
```

I need to find *just one* solution (or find out that there are none).

I have a *P*-core machine. From both time and memory efficiency considerations, it only makes sense to search along *P* different branches in parallel.

For example, suppose you have four branches of about the same computational complexity (corresponding to *T* seconds of CPU time), and each of them has an answer.

If you evaluate all four branches truly in parallel on a dual-core machine, then they all will finish in about *2T* seconds.

If you evaluate just the first two branches and postpone the other two, then you'll get an answer in only *T* seconds, also using twice as less memory.

My question is, is it possible to use any of the parallel Haskell infrastructure (Par monad, parallel strategies, ...) to achieve this, or do I have to use lower-level tools like async?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Data_Parallel_Haskell ?

Comment: I am aware of it, but I don't see how it can address my problem.

Comment: Nested data parallelism is ideal for tree structures

Comment: Also DPH will automatically handle turning a nested structure into a flat one that can be automatically vectorized, so you don't have to worry about optimizing it by hand. The downside is that you have to change your code to work with it a fair bit.

Comment: If your problem is simply recursively climbing down the tree to visit all the leaves, and cost per step-down is very small, the overhead of forking may dominate your computation leading to a net loss in performance.  OTOH, if you have N cores, and the tree is well distributed, you might just divide the top part of the tree into N pieces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Strategies and the Par monad will only start evaluating a new parallel task if there is a CPU available, so in your example with four branches on a 2-core machine, only two will be evaluated.  Furthermore, Strategies will GC the other tasks once you have an answer (although it might take a while to do that).

However, if each of those two branches creates more tasks, then you probably wanted to give priority to the newer tasks (i.e., depth-first), but Strategies at least will give priority to the older tasks.  The Par monad I think gives priority to the newer ones (but I'd have to check that), however the Par monad will evaluate all the tasks before returning an answer, because that is how it enforces determinism.

So probably the only way to get this to work exactly as you want it, at the moment, is to write a custom scheduler for the Par monad.

Answer (score 1):

At least `Par` monad and strategies from `parallel` package allow to build only pure, unconditional parallel systems, which look prettily on such pictures:

```
 a
/ \
b c
\ /\
 d  e
 \ ...
```

While in general case you really need impure inter-thread communications:

```
solve :: Tree a -> Maybe a

smartPartition :: Tree a -> Int -> [[Tree a]]
smartPartition tree P = ... -- split the tree in fairly even chunks,
                            -- one per each machine core

solveP :: Tree a -> IO (Maybe a)
solveP tree = do
    resRef <- newIORef Nothing
    results <- parallel (map work (smartPartition tree))
    return (msum results)
  where work [] = return Nothing
        work (t:ts) = do
            res <- readIORef resRef
            if (isJust res) then (return res) else do
                let tRes = solve t
                if (isNothing tRes) then (work ts) else do
                    writeIORef tRes
                    return tRes
```

However if your single leaf computations are sufficiently *and equally* expensive, unsing strategies *should not* (I'm not sure) harm performance much:

```
partitionLeafs :: Tree a -> Int -> [[Tree a]]

solveP :: Tree a -> Maybe a
solveP = msum . map step . transpose . partitionLeafs
  where step = msum . parMap rdeepseq solve
```

P. S. I feel I understand field of the problem not better than you (at least), so you likely already know all the above. I've written this answer to develop discussion, because the question is very interesting for me.

Comment: If I were to write an IO solution, it'd be a bit different, actually. I'd just set up a semaphore (say, in the form of `TVar`) and wait for a "permission token" to start exploring a new branch. I wouldn't even need parallel strategies — just plain forkIO/async.

The reason is that the tree is lazily generated and splitting it into chunks already means unnecessary evaluation. Also, in your solution I'd need to make assumption (everything is roughly computationally equal; which chunk size is enough) that I don't need to make. Instead, I can just schedule evaluation as I walk the tree.

Comment: ... but what this question is really about is whether it's possible to do this completely inside the Parallel Haskell framework, without resorting to explicit concurrency stuff.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka I thought you have pretty small tree of "expensive" leafs. Otherwise I agree with [Ira Baxter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322586/parallel-tree-search/17328540#comment25132294_17322586).